# Howto hide a Listings or Verbatim environment using a \newif enable command

Tags: macros

Due to make life easier I want to create a Exercise sheet for a lecture including the corresponding solutions. Therefore I defined a `\newif` to control whether the solution should be included or not. That worked fine until I need a `lstlisting` or a `verbatim` environment in it.  The following code is the minimal example for the error, it works with `verbatim` too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\newif\ifsolution 
\solutionfalse

\ifsolution
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{#1}
\else
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{}
\fi

\begin{document}
This is always shown. 
\solution{The listing is only shown if ifsolution is true.
\begin{lstlisting}
 Test
\end{lstlisting}
}
\end{document}
```

Setting `solution` to true produces the error. How can I defined a command or an environment with this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first assessment was wrong, but like Gonzalo kindly noted

> verbatim material cannot appear in the argument of standard commands

A solution that does work is, not using any arguments:

```
\ifsolution
\def\solution{\relax}
\else
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{}
\fi
```

But you can also use the `comment` package. It provides the ability to easily define a certain environment as `comment`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{solution}
%\includecomment{solution}

\begin{document}
This is always shown. 
\begin{solution}
    The listing is only shown if ifsolution is true.
\begin{lstlisting}
 Test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

With `\excludecomment{solution}` the solutions won't be shown and when you write `\includecomment{solution}` instead, they will be shown.

Comment: The problem is that verbatim material cannot appear in the argument of standard commands.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Mmh, seems I assumed too much and tested too little. I better just keep the second solution.

Comment: Actually `\newcommand` uses `\long`, while `\newcommand*` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, your first idea is the one I need in my document.

Comment: The name is Gonzalo ;-).

Comment: Oh... pardon me, I must have always read it wrong ^^

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: [The name is Medina. Gonzalo Medina.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ye8KvYKn9-0) - a secret agent who holds the rare double-O prefix - the license to TeX.

Comment: ``\excludecomment{mybox}`` doesn't work with 
``\newtcblisting{mybox}[2][]{... blabla`` do you confirm?

Comment: @PatrickT: Note that in my answer I don't use `\excludecomment{lstlisting}`. The `comment` package and `\newtcblisting` are both defining the `mybox` environment. If you need more help, you should probably ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks canaaerus! I found a workaround for my problem, basically defining the listings and such once and for all inside conditionals, rather than trying to redefine them as I went along, which was causing me a lot of grief. :-[