# Showing/Hiding verbatim environment based on boolean condition

Tags: environments, conditionals, verbatim

I would like to show and hide a `verbatim` or `spverbatim` environment based on a boolean condition (sth. like `\showenv`). I tried the solutions proposed at [Hide custom environment content based on boolean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/), e.g. when using

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myenv}{
  \ifshow
    \spverbatim{\BODY}
  \fi}

...

\begin{myenv}
Test 1
  Test 2
\end{myenv}
```

I get the following errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\env@myenv@process -> \ifshow
! Extra \else.
! Extra \fi.
! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
! Paragraph ended before \verbatim@test was complete.
```

Comment: You can't use `\NewEnviron` for processing verbatim material. There are already similar questions on the site.

Comment: I tried some proposed solutions but they either don't work (e.g. the first one from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69009/) or I get the same or similar errors (the second one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comment-environment of the verbatim package is what you are searching for. Here is an example how to define myenv according to your requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newif\ifshow

\newenvironment{myenv}%
{\ifshow\expandafter\verbatim\else\expandafter\comment\fi}%
{\ifshow\expandafter\endverbatim\else\expandafter\endcomment\fi}

\begin{document}

\showtrue
\begin{myenv}
Test 1
% some verbatim text
\end{myenv}

\showfalse
\begin{myenv}
Test 2
% some verbatim text
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```